# Sitecore 8 ribbons missing from toolbar

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Suddenly all ribbons are not coming in Sitecore 8 one of my project.
For example If I am going in publish menu I cannot see any option there.
To solve this issue, I have updated all three folders and config file "sitecore,sitecore_modules,sitecore files & web.config" but still ribbons are not coming for me.

Please assist me what can be solution for this issue.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes It is not coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your effort. I just copied fresh "Content Editor.js" in Content Manger folder and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your ribbons are just collapsed (not expanded). To expand them back there is a little check on the right hand side of the screen. Check the screenshot for reference

[image]

Comment: My ribbons are not collapsed. This little check is not coming for me.
This application was running fine.

Comment: You don`t have check at all ?

Comment: @S.K can you provide a screenshot of you entire bar ? From end to end.

Comment: Lol ! Any js exceptions ? The ribbon strips are actually stored in the core database. Have you made any changes there?

Comment: Not getting any JS exception. Yes i am using core DB functionality. But this was running fine for me from last 20 days. This issue has occurred today only.

Comment: No idea then :( sorry You might want to contact sitecore support.

Comment: can you add to your url : &sc_lang=en to change the sitecore client language

Comment: yes I am able .. but still menu ribbons not displaying for me

Comment: Can you replace your Sitecore folder and core db with fresh versions check you see the ribbon then redeploy your code over top?

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem and this issue usually coming by difference the version sitecore when you want to integrate with your solution. Try with another sitecore (sitecore,sitecore_modules,sitecore files) version that it